# Which cocos2d scene is currently active when returning from suspended app state

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, multitasking

The environment is an iOS device with multitasking support, like an iPhone4.
I'm in a cocos2d app with a Main Menu that leads to several Scenes.

[image]

If I switch to another app using the taskbar, then switch back, how do I programmatically tell which scene is active?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just check CCDirector's runningScene property in your app delegate's applicationWillEnterForeground: method? If you subclass CCScene you could just check the scene's class, otherwise you may want to add some other sort of identifier to each scene.

Comment: Checking the class gets me a CCScene, which doesn't really narrow it down.

Comment: You could always use `CCScene`'s `tag` property, and give each scene a distinctive tag when you create it, and then check the running scene's tag in `applicationWillEnterForeground:`.

Answer (score 0):

you could add an identifier for the CCSCene class such as `int sceneID` or `typedef enum { mainMenuID = 0, playSceneID, helpSceneID, aboutSceneID } sceneID` and then simply assign each of these in the `init` method of each scene... then you can retrieve it in `applicationWillEnterForeground:` like so:

`int theSceneID = [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] classID];`

but like Zaid suggested, it is alot easier to use the tag of CCScene.